# How to keep a user logged in

Tags: session

Is the only way to use session cookie if I wanna keep a user logged in even if he has restarted the computer?

I would appreciate all kinds of solutions for different scenarios.

I am using Node.js/Express.

Comment: What if 'your server' restarts? You still want it then?

Comment: Which Platform/technology/language???

Comment: There is a blog written http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/ you can try that as well. His post is using socket.io to handle sessions and in the last example he has given the code that will keep the session alive. You can club the cookie and socket.io solutions together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say yes : keeping his IP will not work every time.

Depending on your context (intranet application most often), you may also have a look at SSO solutions like kerberos

Answer (score 0):

For further searches like me, this issue is better described/explained in this post on Stack:

[Managing Sessions in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737062/managing-sessions-in-nodejs)