# nodejs chat server persistant across the pages

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, chat

I have to create a chat server page chat.html using node.js. I have used a a couple of modules like http://chat.nodejs.org. The problem is when I moved from chat.html page to some other page of my application like about.html and come back to chat.html I need to login again and it consider me a fresh joiner.

Is there any way/module using which I can persist the chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach would be to use sessions, to identify the user and load their chat history from a database.

You could also consider just storing their history into a cookie/localStorage and thus save some load on the server, unless you need to identify or store the history anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set up sessions in your application. Rather than describe that here, I'll link this popular answer:

[Managing Sessions in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737062/managing-sessions-in-nodejs)