# Server-Side JavaScript Sessions

Tags: javascript, session, authentication, server-side, exacttarget

I am working in a proprietary environment (ExactTarget) where I have to use Server-Side JavaScript, which I am not familiar with. I need to create a login for pw protected pages. Anyone know how to create/start sessions, set session variables, etc. in SSJS? I can't seem to find much info out there.

Comment: There are dozens of server side JavaScript environments, some are more common than others (node.js and Classic ASP are probably the most common), but the details will depend on the environment.

Comment: Are you trying to authenticate ExactTarget users (those with ExactTarget licenses) or external users?  In my experience, there isn't a lot of session support, but if the user's have ExactTarget licenses, there is at least authentication support (or so they claim)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use node, then you should refer to this thread on sessions on node.js [Managing Sessions in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737062/managing-sessions-in-nodejs)