# Replacing server-side language by JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, database, server-side

I would like to know if it is possible to replace a server side language (PHP, C#, Java EE, etc) by JavaScript to do the same work (accessing a database, using sessions, etc).

I hate PHP the more I use it, I'm too lazy to learn the EE part of Java, and I don't know C#, and since I like JavaScript, I'd like to use it for that.

Is it possible / doable ? If yes, can you point me into the right direction to get the required software ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at Node.JS...  It is basically server side Javascript.

http://nodejs.org/

Comment: Thanks ! Is it possible to access databases and use sessions with this ? It is already handled or will i have to code is myself ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737062/managing-sessions-in-nodejs

Comment: Yes. Just read the documentation.