# Timeout on multiple pages using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am developing a script for online exams portal, here I need to maintain timeout for a online exam on multiple pages (each question is in one page) .
I know how to manage timeout on one page.

Can anybody suggest me how to manage timeout on multiple pages?

Comment: You have to do it serverside.

Comment: Do you mean exam participants have a time limit on how long they have to complete the whole exam?

Comment: Server-side, unless you want people cheating in 5000 hours of time.

Comment: **use `onbeforeunload` to keep thenm your activev and attetntaive cliewnts for as long as you  like.**

Comment: Using some type of Session. With Javascript server side I would reccomend Node.js check out this question as a refrence: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737062/managing-sessions-in-nodejs